# Recommendation for tool to verify data integrity in DB table

Tags: sql

We have an SQL DB consisting of 15 different tables. These tables are being populated from 7 different data sources. I have access to the all 7 data source files (in .csv format). Now, I would like to compare and verify the populated tables in automated fashion to confirm the integrity of the data.

Is there any open source tools to perform the integrity verification of data in the DB tables.